# При переносе комментариев в чат экранирование разворачивается больше раз, чем нужно

Tags: дефект, комментарии, чат

Похоже, что при переносе ветки комментариев в чат экранирование обратными слэшами производится ещё один (как минимум) лишний раз, в результате чего исходные комментарии не соответствуют тому, что оказывается в сообщениях чата.

Живой пример в комментариях под [вопросом](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/543735/181100) и в [образованном из них чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/42331/discussion-between-d-side-and-maxim-cherevatov):

> Там тоже нету верха трейса ¯\_(ツ)_/¯ – [D-side](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/181100/d-side) [13 мин. назад](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/543735/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B4%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B6%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%B2-devise-rails?noredirect=1#comment690663_543735)

В исходном тексте комментария в shruggie (`¯\_(ツ)_/¯`) идёт два обратных слэша подряд, если забыть второй, то он обработается, как экранирование для `_`. Откуда у этого растут ноги, известно и понятно.

```
Там тоже нету верха трейса ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯
```

Но в [сообщении чата](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/30953072#30953072) вообще ни одного обратного слэша нет:

```
Там тоже нету верха трейса ¯_(ツ)_/¯
```

Comment: Видишь слэш? Нет. А он есть!

Comment: @NickVolynkin украли `:О`

Comment: Предлагаю накидать тут разные похожие варианты в комментариях. Что там ещё может экранироваться? Потом я их все перенесу в чат, не удаляя здесь. Так мы сможем проверить другие ситуации, может быть ещё что-то найдем.

Comment: М. Тогда для начала закину свой, чтобы изолировать баг-репорт от внешних возмущений вроде спонтанного самоуничтожения вопроса ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: Ещё можно попробовать сломанную вариацию shruggie. Если вывод пропускается через Markdown дважды, то `_` исчезнут и станут курсивом на смайлик: ¯\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: Ну что, заходит как-то тестировщик в бар и \ \\ \\\ \\\\ \\\\\ \a\b\c\d\e\f\g\h\j\k\l\m\n\o\p\q\r\s\t\u\v\w\x\y\z\,\.\/\?\|\=\+\-\_\(\)\1\2\3\4\5\6\7\8\9\0\§\±\~\``\`\`\``\\``\<\><b>bold<\b>**bold2**<i>italic</i>,_anotheritalic_ and __moreitalic__

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещен в чат](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/42335/discussion-on-question-by-d-side-------).