# Уходит часть смайлика при написании комментария/ответа/вопроса

Tags: обсуждение, дефект, статус-так-задумано

При написании такого смайлика в комментарии, вопросе, ответе или чате, уходит левый слеш `\`. Что это значит? Я думаю, что это SO очищает комментарии, ответы и вопросы от служебных символов.
[image: textfac.es]переходит в[image]

Comment: https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%AD%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5_%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2

Comment: @NickVolynkin Экранирование символов и на SO есть?

Comment: @VerNick, есть ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: Вы будете удивлены, когда "пропадет" кусок текста, заключенный в угловые скобки: `<aaa>`

Comment: @АндрейNOP ¯\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: @АндрейNOP Хотя писал я со слешем :)

Comment: `¯\_(ツ)_/¯ ` -> ¯\_(ツ)_/¯  `¯\\_(ツ)_/¯ ` -> ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯ работает же

Comment: @VerNick https://media.tenor.com/images/a170ca13e7ad99049d65ade3ba83ab34/tenor.gif

Comment: @Anton Ок, буду использовать ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: @АндрейNOP https://i.stack.imgur.com/nY5q9.jpg

Comment: @NickVolynkin а чего красную метку [так-задумано] не влепили?

Comment: @älёxölüt, ну я влепил. И вообще, дубликат же?

Comment: @Qwertiy дубликат чего?

Comment: @Qwertiy Как это может быть дубликат?

Comment: @älёxölüt, ладно, не дубликат, но сходство есть: https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/3368/178988

Comment: SO - база знаний, здесь не место вашим смайликам :D

Comment: @yolosora Ну пошутить над кодом нельзя, что ли?

Comment: На so не любят шутки!

Comment: @yolosora Да ладно? https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/5069/%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%BC%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%8F%D1%81%D0%B0-%D0%B1%D1%8D%D1%82%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B0

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Из [документации Markdown](https://daringfireball.net/projects/markdown/syntax#backslash)

> Markdown provides backslash escapes for the following characters:
>
> ```
> \   backslash  
> `   backtick  
> *   asterisk  
> _   underscore  
> {}  curly braces  
> []  square brackets  
> ()  parentheses  
> #   hash mark  
> +   plus sign  
> -   minus sign (hyphen)  
> .   dot  
> !   exclamation mark
> ```

Чтобы вместо экранирования вставить символ backslash "как есть", нужно продублировать его

`\\_` = \_