# Ломается форматирование при правке из очереди проверок

Tags: дефект, статус-так-задумано, очередь-проверок

Словил странный баг. В [очереди проверок наткнулся](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/306744) на [ответ](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/906287/213987), в котором захотел поправить слегка форматирование - чтобы код подсвечивался как код.

Нажал "править", ввёл ручками 4 пробела в начале строки, нажал "сохранить". Ну и пошёл дальше.

А потом получаю уведомление от автора ответа, что правка "сломала" ответ - добавились лишние слэши. Посмотрел [ревизии](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/posts/906287/revisions) - да, поломала.

Не могу списать на грейс-период: я правил через час, как автор ответа запостил его.

Баг? (Воспроизводить не пробовал, т.к. пост должен попасть в очередь на проверку)

Answer (score 7):

Правка изменила ровно то, что ты хотел - превратила текст в код. При этом использованное в тексте экранирование перестало быть экранированием и проявилось как есть:

> [image: скриншот правки]

Answer (score 6):

Не поломало. Просто последовательность символов `\\` по разному отображается без выделения кодом и с ним, из-за [экранирования](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/8139/%D0%A3%D1%85%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B8%D1%82-%D1%87%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%82%D1%8C-%D1%81%D0%BC%D0%B0%D0%B9%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B0-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8-%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B8-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%B0-%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%B0/8140#8140).